# Why won't my grid sidebar display content next to my main area?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, media-queries

I have a sidebar inside my Desktop @media query and it's only used in that media query.

When I extend the viewport for that @media query it shows up fine and the main area has made space for my sidebar.

However, the sidebar is only displaying content next to my advert and not next to my main area. It's just blank space as if space has been allocated for the sidebar but can't be used.

What am I missing here?

I've tried lots of combinations of grid-area-template. No luck.

[image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <header> Some Anchors </header>
    <advert class="bg-righttoleft"></advert> 
    <main> LOTS OF CONTENT </main>
    <sidebar> A background-image in CSS </sidebar>
    <footer>Maximilian Crosby ©</footer>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container  { /* Mobile */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "advert"
    "main"
    "footer";
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen /* Tablet */
  and (min-width: 885px) {
    .container  {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
      grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "advert"
      "main"
      "footer";
    }
  }

@media only screen /* Big Tablet */
  and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .column-text  {
      min-height: 260px;
      padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
  }

@media screen /* Desktop/Laptop */
  and (min-width: 1900px) {
    .container  {
    max-width: 2500px;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "sidebar advert"
      "sidebar main"
      "footer footer";
    }

    sidebar  {
      background: url(./history-vr-banner.jpg);
    }
  }
```

I expect the sidebar content to use the entirety of the space beside the advert and main areas.

It's only covering the area beside the advert at the moment. NOTE: space has been allocated for the sidebar next to the main area as the main area has shifted its self to the right of the viewport leaving empty space to the left.

Comment: With my Desktop @media if I change the top left area (header) to sidebar as well it only displays the background in the sidebar area next to the header area. Therefore I think it's only using the top sidebar area specified to display content.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. Your container class put everything text-center including the image. Remove text-center from container and it should work.

Comment: I don't think that's it. You can see the problem more clearly with the picture that I've added.